# How do I get my ui-widget-content container to highlight on a drop event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery to implement a drag and drop operation.  I have two containers, that use the class ui-widget-content.

I have enabled the binding using

```
            // let the todo be droppable as well, accepting items from the done
        $newtask.droppable({
            accept: "#inprogress li, #done li",
            activeClass: "custom-state-active",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                recycleImage( ui.draggable );
            }
        });
```

while my container will accept the incoming LI, it does not highlight

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the activeClass: "ui-state-highlight"